# Add items to a list without the textinput method

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

```
import turtle
t = turtle.Turtle()
list = []

def left():
    list.append("l")
    t.penup()
    t.speed(3)
    t.goto(-300,100)

def right():
    list.append("r")
    ball_pen.penup()
    ball_pen.speed(3)
    ball_pen.goto(300,100)

def center():
    list.append("c")
    t.penup()
    t.speed(3)
    t.goto(0,100)

screen.onkeypress(left,"l")
screen.onkeypress(right,"r")
screen.onkeypress(center,"c")
screen.listen()

print(list)
```

i want to add "l" or "r" or "c" in list after my input..
how can i add letter in list after my input without using textinput function, but with onkeypress function??
i added list append function but it doesn't work ...

Comment: I took the liberty to change your title, as `python` and `turtle` are tags and not words really appropriate for a title. It's better to describe the actual issue in the title and not the tech stack used :)

Comment: thank you!! it looks better:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is generally OK, it's just that your `print()` statement is in the wrong place:

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle

def left():
    turtle.penup()
    turtle.speed(3)
    turtle.goto(-300, 100)

    movements.append('l')
    print(movements)

def right():
    turtle.penup()
    turtle.speed(3)
    turtle.goto(300, 100)

    movements.append('r')
    print(movements)

def center():
    turtle.penup()
    turtle.speed(3)
    turtle.goto(0, 100)

    movements.append('c')
    print(movements)

screen = Screen()
turtle = Turtle()

movements = []

screen.onkeypress(left, 'l')
screen.onkeypress(right, 'r')
screen.onkeypress(center, 'c')
screen.listen()

screen.mainloop()
```

Avoid using Python keywords like `list` as your own variable names.